# LinearRegression in Python giving incorrect results?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have a comma-separated CSV file with two numerical columns - inputs and outputs. They are correlated in a (more or less linear function), see below. The sample I have is very small.

Below, is the Python code I wrote using sklearn in order to predict values. Somehow it's not giving me the correct values (reasonable predictions). I am quite new to this, so please bear with me.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, names=['kg', 'cm'])
labels = data['kg']
train1 = data.drop(['kg'], axis=1) # In all honesty, I don't understand this.

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train1, labels, test_size=0.10, random_state=2)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
reg.score(x_test, y_test)
reg.predict(80) # Gives an incorrect value of about 108.
```

Data.

```
89,155
86,161
82.5,168
79.25,174
76.25,182
73,189
70,198
66.66,207
63.5,218
60.25,229
57,241
54,257
51,259
```

Comment: I think for simple linear regression, method available in scipy, are easier to use and very fast. for more advanced statistical analysis statsmodels is very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are having problem understanding your own code.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, names=['kg', 'cm'])
labels = data['kg']
train1 = data.drop(['kg'], axis=1) # In all honesty, I don't understand this.
```

Until here what you have done is that you have loaded the dataframe. After that you seprated X and y from the dataset.

**labels** represent the y values.
**train1** represent the x values.

Since you wrote you can't understand :-  **train1 = data.drop(['kg'], axis=1)**
Let me explain this. What this does is that from the dataframe which consist both column 'kg' and 'cm'. It removes 'kg' column (axis = 1 means column, axis = 0 means row). Hence only 'cm' is remaining which is your x.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train1, labels, test_size=0.10, random_state=2)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
reg.score(x_test, y_test)
reg.predict(80) # Gives an incorrect value of about 108.
```

Now you train the model on x values which represents 'cm' and y values which represent 'kg'.

When you predict(80) what happens is that you input the 'cm' value to be 80. Let me just plot the 'cm' vs 'kg' for training data.

[image]

When you input height as 80 this means that you are going more left, even more left than your plot. Hence as you can see x decrease y increase. It means that as 'cm' decrease means 'kg' increase. Hence ouput is 110 which is more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I understand why the value (110) would decrease, but it seems to be decreasing too quickly...? In other words, it seems to become a hockey stick shape on the left hand side. Also, "only 'cm' is remaining which is your x. " - is that right? Maybe I dropped the column incorrectly...?

Comment: No, the dropping of column is correct. Since there are 2 columns, 1 will be y and other 1 will be X. To know if your prediction is right or wrong, you can do one thing, you can plot the linear regression line in plot with  x values from 50 to 270 and you will see that the rate is same (its not hockey stick but straight line).

Comment: You can also see one thing. X= 240 => y = 60. X = 160 => y = 85 so by that rate and intution X = 80 so it will become near 110.

Comment: you are right and I'm an idiot. I confused X with Y. I thought since labels was "kg", I would ask for "kg" and get "cm", but it's the other way round! Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from io import StringIO
input_data=StringIO("""89,155\n
86,161\n
82.5,168\n
79.25,174\n
76.25,182\n
73,189\n
70,198\n
66.66,207\n
63.5,218\n
60.25,229\n
57,241\n
54,257\n
51,259""")


import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(input_data, header=None, names=['kg', 'cm'])
labels = data['cm']
train1 = data.drop(['cm'], axis=1) #This is similar to selecting the kg column

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train1, labels, test_size=0.10, random_state=2)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_train, y_train)
reg.score(x_test, y_test)

import numpy as np
reg.predict(np.array([80]).reshape(-1, 1)) # 172.65013306.
```

Comment: This works as well, thank you, David! Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are having problems with small data size. The code flow looks normal to me, I would suggest you try to find the p-value for the input-output. This will tell you if the correlation found from your linear regression is significant or not (p-value <0.05).

You can find p-value using:

```
 from scipy.stats import linregress
 print(linregress(input, output))
```

To find p-value using scikit learn you probably need to use the formula to find p-value. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I did not use it in the end.